Garbage Management System please help to draw the er diagram
Steps to Draw the ER Diagram

Draw Rectangles for Each Entity:

Customer
Collector
Admin
User


Add Attributes Inside Each Entity:

Customer:

Customer_ID (Primary Key)
Name
Address
Contact_Details
Email
Reward_Points


Collector:

Collector_ID (Primary Key)
Name
Contact_Details
Assigned_Location


Admin:

Admin_ID (Primary Key)
Name
Email
Password


User:

User_ID (Primary Key)
Name
Email
Password
Role (Admin, Customer, Collector)




Draw Relationships Between Entities:

Admin Manages Users:

Draw a line between Admin and User.
Label the relationship as "manages."
Indicate cardinality as 1:M (One Admin manages many Users).


Admin Manages Customers:

Draw a line between Admin and Customer.
Label the relationship as "manages."
Indicate cardinality as 1:M (One Admin manages many Customers).


Admin Manages Collectors:

Draw a line between Admin and Collector.
Label the relationship as "manages."
Indicate cardinality as 1:M (One Admin manages many Collectors).


Collector Assigned to Customers:

Draw a line between Collector and Customer.
Label the relationship as "assigned_to."
Indicate cardinality as 1:M (One Collector is assigned to many Customers).




Indicate Cardinalities:

Use symbols near the relationships to indicate cardinalities:

1 for one
M for many





Resulting Diagram Structure

Admin (1) --- (manages) --- (M) User
Admin (1) --- (manages) --- (M) Customer
Admin (1) --- (manages) --- (M) Collector
Collector (1) --- (assigned_to) --- (M) Customer

Final ER Diagram:

Draw rectangles for each entity and label them.
Inside each rectangle, list the attributes.
Draw lines between rectangles to show relationships.
Add cardinalities (1:M) on the lines to indicate the type of relationship.

You can use diagramming tools like Lucidchart, draw.io, or even paper to sketch this out.
If you need, I can describe or draw this further using text or ASCII, or guide you with tools to create it digitally. please draw the er diagram for this with cardinalty and relationship

Did you have a look at e.g. plantuml (see e.g. https://plantuml.com/)
